# Cursor go to first place after period operator(.) in EditText

Tags: android

Hi I am using the EditText in my app.when i enter .(Period ) after then the cursor go to first position in EditText.but i want to display the characters after . when i enter . for this what can i do give me some suggestions. and i want to enter numbers only in EditText if no character is displayed when i type any special character from keyboard for this what can i do? give me some suggestions .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should take a look to TextWatcher